# Uploading a file from applet to server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, applet, vaadin

I have an applet which records sound. This applet is integrated in VAADIN application using AppletIntegration addon. The applet runs just fine. Now, I have to upload that recorded file to my server, on which the vaadin app is running. How could I do that. Any solution , any ideas ?
Thanks.

Comment: I tried some thing like I get the external IP of the computer on which the Apache tomcat is running then make it as a URL and then upload the file to that url. But accessing the application using that external IP is not working, it gives "Cannot establish connection to the server". So I am stuck here.

Comment: How is it going? Did you succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

Emm...

You can use HttpComponents its [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/index.html) + [FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) libs combination;

For more detailed information you can read [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html) and [this](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html) examples

P.S.
Please report if that helps

Good luck